# Different Data Types Operations double-float

Tags: java, compilation, floating-point, double

I know that when having to do with operators in Java , and different data types, then the result is promoting to the larger of the data types 
So, because double is larger than float, when having for example

```
double z=39.21;
float w=2.1F;
System.out.println(z+w );
```

The result z+w will be of double type. 
If I don't put the F on the float data type, then the float is assumed to be double.

So why the below code does not compile??

```
double z=39.21;
float w=2.1;
System.out.println(z+w );
```

Shouldn't the result just be double, if both z and w are considered double??? 
Instead it throws:

```
Arithmetic.java:26: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float 
float w=2.1; 
        ^ 
1 error
```

Also, when

```
short x = 14;
float y = 13;
double z = 30;
System.out.println( x * y / z);
```

First, the short gets converted to int. Then the int gets converted to Float.  Then multiplication happens.

Why does in this case compile , since we have an operation between a double and a float without an F??????

I cannot seem to understand that case can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float w = 2.1;  // error
```

By **default**, 2.1 is a Double literal.

Compiler wants an assurance from your side that you're ready to perform the narrowing conversion, that's why it expects a F (or f) after the literal.

If you don't put an `F`(OR `f`), it will result in compilation error.

```
float y = 13;   // works successfully.
```

Whereas, in the other case, 13 is an Integer literal. So, it easily gets into a float type. Therefore, the code works successfully.